# Let G and H be groups, with A a normal subgroup of G and B a normal subgroup of H. Show that A × B is a normal subgroup of G × H

Tags: abstract-algebra

I could prove that A × B is a subgroup of G × H, but how to prove A × B is a normal subgroup of G × H? I missed a lecture, can anyone tell me what is a normal subgroup and how to prove a subgroup is a normal subgroup?

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but have you looked at the Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup Especially the first definition in the "Definitions" section.

Comment: There is a natural homomorphism from G × H to G/A × H/B. What is its kernel?

Answer (score 1):

A normal subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is defined as a subgroup where the left and right cosets are precisely the same; that is, $gH=Hg$ for all $g \in G$. To show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ it suffices to show that, for all $g \in G$, $gHg^{-1} \subset H$.

Here's the section on normal subgroups from the open source textbook I use. You'll find the theorem that says when a subgroup is a normal subgroup here. http://abstract.pugetsound.edu/aata/section-factor-groups.html

Comment: Thanks for replying me. I know that I have to prove gHg−1⊂H, but gg−1=1, so gHg−1=H, for sure every time we have gHg−1=H⊂H. So since gHg−1⊂H is a fact, why we should prove it? This part I really get confused.

Comment: Your argument is flawed. You can't say that $gHg^{-1}=H$ because $gg^{-1}$ is the identity unless $G$ is an abelian group. If $G$ is in fact abelian, then it can easily be shown that every subgroup is normal. As a set $gHg^{-1}=\{ghg^{-1} | h \in H\}$, which is why your argument only holds for abelian groups. If you are still confused, try looking at some examples. Pick a group and see how its subgroups behave under conjugation. Software is really helpful for exploring these ideas.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome :)